# Error: cannot override "to" (operation="overrides", overrides=["to"], code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.6.2)

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, etherjs

I'm facing this error while I'm trying to mint with sending transaction

```
                const tx = {
                  from: accounts[0],
                  to: ContractAddress,
                  value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0005"),
                  nonce: await provider.getTransactionCount(
                    accounts[0],
                    "latest"
                  ),
                  gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(10000),
                  gasPrice: ethers.utils.hexlify(
                    parseInt(await provider.getGasPrice())
                  ),
                };

                await contract.CustomMint(1, tx);
                signer.sendTransaction(tx).then((transaction) => {
                  console.dir(transaction);
                  alert("Send finished!");
                  if (transaction) {
                    alert("Minted! Check Your Opensea Account For CrownNFT!");
                    handleNewNotification("Success");
                    SetMinting(false);
                  }
                });
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
```

Comment: Your approach is very strange. Why you need to send the tx as a paramter to the CustomMint call?

Comment: So how can I use this approach? because the mint function is payable. I want to mint nft with a custom price which is described on my dapp so which approach is possible for that?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the `CustomMint()` function code?